# Does the JavaScript onclick event not work on <select> <option>'s?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

For some reason the code below it is not working correctly. Unless I'm being quite stupid with my JavaScript I can't see what's going wrong besides the onclick events not firing on the `<option>`s.

```js
function showOther() {
  document.getElementById('other').value = "";
  document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('otherBR').style.display = 'block';
}

function hideOther() {
  document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('otherBR').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#other {
  display: none;
}
#otherBr {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="drop_down">
  <option value="choose" onclick="hideOther();">Please choose</option>
  <option value="Allure" onclick="hideOther();">Allure</option>
  <option value="Elle" onclick="hideOther();">Elle</option>
  <option value="In-Style" onclick="hideOther();">In-Style</option>
  <option value="other" id="otherOption" onclick="showOther();">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="fields_where" id="other" placeholder="Other" />
<br id="otherBR" />
```

Comment: You'll need to hook onto the select element instead.

Comment: Use the "onchange" event. The options should be considered part of the parent select and not separate controls.

Comment: @laaposto OP's example doesn't use jQuery...

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I can use jQuery if necessary. I'm just new to it so I didn't want to look all of that up as the client project is due tomorrow.

Comment: If you have an answer then post it as an answer, not as a comment!

Comment: @user3179156 You don't need it.

Comment: If you do only this, you shouldn't add additional bits to your website using jQuery (which is really heavy, over 100kb).

Comment: @Adshi jQuery is already included for their site so its not unreasonable to use it. I just picked it up out of necessity for an ajax call and I like it, but I've yet to mess around with all of the available functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this function to your JS:

```
function showHideOther(){
    if (document.getElementById('drop_down').value == 'other') {
         showOther();   
    } else {
         hideOther();   
    }
}
```

And change your select element like this:

```
<select name="" id="drop_down" onchange="showHideOther();">
        <option value="choose">Please choose</option>
        <option value="Allure">Allure</option>
        <option value="Elle">Elle</option>
        <option value="In-Style">In-Style</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

```js
function showHideOther() {
  if (document.getElementById('drop_down').value == 'other') {
    showOther();
  } else {
    hideOther();
  }
}

function showOther() {
  document.getElementById('other').value = "";
  document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('otherBR').style.display = 'block';
}

function hideOther() {
  document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('otherBR').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#other {
  display: none;
}
#otherBr {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="drop_down" onchange="showHideOther();">
  <option value="choose">Please choose</option>
  <option value="Allure">Allure</option>
  <option value="Elle">Elle</option>
  <option value="In-Style">In-Style</option>
  <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="fields_where" id="other" placeholder="Other" />
<br id="otherBR" />
```

Comment: It works in jsFiddle if you change the load option to No wrap... see here: http://jsfiddle.net/gLML3/22/

Comment: Great, and for clarification on implementation what does No Wrap mean in terms of using it on your own site. As in should that code not go in the header? Or the body? Or something else entirely?

Comment: It means that the function declarations are not wrapped in other code, such as `window.onLoad = function() { function showHideOther(){...} }`

Answer (score 2):

An answer with JS only, not jQuery:

**onclick** event in option tag is just recognized by Firefox. If you need a solution that works on all browsers such as IE or Chrome you can use **onchange** event on your "**Select**" element.

HTML :

```
<select name="" id="drop_down" onchange="showHideOther(this.value);">
    <option value="choose" ">Please choose</option>
    <option value="Allure">Allure</option>
    <option value="Elle" >Elle</option>
    <option value="In-Style" >In-Style</option>
    <option value="other" id="otherOption">Other</option>
</select>
```

JS defined in the html head section as script:

```
function showHideOther(value){
    alert(value);
    if (value==='other'){
        document.getElementById('other').value = "";
        document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'block'; 
        document.getElementById('otherBR').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
            document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none'; 
            document.getElementById('otherBR').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

JSFiddle sample working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/amontellano/gLML3/14/

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't see how your code is working at all. You have errors in the HTML and showOther is never called.

Comment: I'm answering also that you need to use onchange event in select element instead of onclick inside your options. I think the current sample does what you need now my friend.

Comment: @user3179156 My sample is working fine in JSFiddle. Try it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gLML3/12/)

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById('drop_down');

dropdown.onchange = function() {
  var selected = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;

  switch(selected) {
    case 'other':
      document.getElementById('other').value = "";
      document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'block'; 
      document.getElementById('otherBR').style.display = 'block';
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none'; 
      document.getElementById('otherBR').style.display = 'none';
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

just add these function to your code:

```
$('#drop_down').on('change', function(){
    ($(this).val() == 'other') ? showOther() : hideOther();
});
```

se here: http://jsfiddle.net/gLML3/7/

Comment: This would require the use of jQuery, which OP is not using.