# Javascript onclick in <option> of <select> not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, android-layout, mobile

It works in normal browser. Does not work on mobile.

Here's what I have:

```js
function processAjax(kat,div)
{
    if(div==1)
    {
        $('#DivCat1').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat2').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat3').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat4').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat5').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat6').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat7').hide('slow', function() {});
    }
    if(div==2)
    {
        $('#DivCat3').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat4').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat5').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat6').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat7').hide('slow', function() {});
    }
    if(div==3)
    {
        $('#DivCat4').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat5').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat6').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat7').hide('slow', function() {});
    }
    if(div==4)
    {
        $('#DivCat5').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat6').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat7').hide('slow', function() {});
    }
    if(div==5)
    {
        $('#DivCat6').hide('slow', function() {});
        $('#DivCat7').hide('slow', function() {});
    }
    if(div==6)
    {
        $('#DivCat7').hide('slow', function() {});
    }
    if(div==7)
    {
        $('#DivCat8').hide('slow', function() {});
    }
    $('#DivCat'+div).show('slow', function() {});
    $('#DivCat'+div).load('katgetir.php?kat='+kat+'&div='+div);

    $('#change').animate({scrollLeft : 500},'slow');
}
```

```html
<select multiple class="form-control">           

  <option id="45" onclick="processAjax(45,1)">Kat</option>

</select>
```

Comment: onclick does not work in options on some desktop browsers too.... use onchange on the select.

Comment: Aside from the issue, you should research the DRY principle. It will massively improve your code.

Comment: You also do not need the callback functions in all of your .hide() and .show()  you can simply put .hide('slow') .  that aside You can always get browser extensions to emulate mobile browsers to test on,  I know firefox and chrome have them.

Comment: There are no click events in some (maybe all?) mobile browsers, only touch events. So you need to capture ontouchstart and ontouchend instead of onclick. Look at the JQuery docs (and JQuery mobile) to look up how to do it on mobile. As noted above, learn a bit about DontRepeatYourself and event delegation. Your function can be written 10 times smaller.

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. As a side effect, doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely that you will get people to up-vote your posts and makes it more likely that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't matter which style your choose (although, IMO, some are more appropriate for JavaScript than others). But, pick one and use it consistently for all code in a single project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the JavaScript onclick event not work on <select> <option>'s?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21029907)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the JavaScript onclick event not work on <select> <option>'s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029907/does-the-javascript-onclick-event-not-work-on-select-options)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are using `onclick`, but on mobile you are not clicking but changing the value of parent select instead. Check this [**link**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=62b6ddca81bd7279b8a4c522aad1db0e) and you will see it works on mobile as well.

Comment: The answer should say add onchange event to your select box like in the above comments on the question

Comment: @GüneySaramalı Thank you for fixing the link to your demo. Do you think you could inline it in your post using the `<!-- begin snippet: ... >` feature from StackOverflow?

Comment: @Cœur I'm doin in that way nowadays =)

Comment: Please put code in your answer. Links to code on external sites should only be used to *supplement* code that's included in a question or answer. An external site should not be the primary repository of such code. Having a link to code on an external site becomes useless when that page dies.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions. This is effective a link only answer and will rot and be useful for no-one very shortly.