# onclick not working for select menu options

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I'm a beginner at HTML, and I have a problem with the onclick and the select (dropdown list).
I know I did something wrong, so can somebody help me?

```html
  <select>
      <option onclick="alert('Hi')">No</option>
      <option onclick="alert('Hi')">Yes</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the JavaScript onclick event not work on <select> <option>'s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029907/does-the-javascript-onclick-event-not-work-on-select-options)

Comment: _"I know I did something wrong"_ - yes, you failed at doing proper research. Even typing your question title into Google verbatim would have given you lots of answers already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `onChange`:

```js
function changed(value){
 alert(value);
}
```

```html
<select onChange="changed(this.value)">
    <option>No</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: When I ran the code on another website, nothing happened.

Comment: @TristanLe what do you mean?

Comment: @TristanLe can you give us the code for your other projects so we can debug?  Something may be wrong about the way that you applied this.

Comment: Also, where would I put the top part?

Comment: @TristanLe inside of a `<script>` tag in the head of your application, or in a separate javascript file.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-javascript-to-html

Answer (score -1):

```
function alert_function(){
  var selected_option = $("#select option:selected").data("alert");
  alert(selected_option);
}

<select id="select" onchange="alert_function();">
    <option data-alert="hi 1">No</option>
    <option data-alert="hi 2">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Who gives a negative score? This is an alternative and explicative way.

Comment: 1) There is no reason to use JQuery here: There are a lot better native solutions, and the question says nothing about JQuery. 2) You did not format your answer using the proper snippet notation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/