# Javascript div toggling on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

Got couple divs that should hide/unhide based on what user has selected in the dropdown list.
I know that problem is in the html part of the code onclick event, thus it doesnt work on smartphones. Any ideas how I could change the code for it to work?

```
    var divs = ["2019vasara", "2019ruduo"];
    var visibleDivId = null;
    function divVisibility(divId) {
      if(visibleDivId === divId) {
        visibleDivId = null;
      } else {
        visibleDivId = divId;
      }
      hideNonVisibleDivs();
    }
    function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
      var i, divId, div;
      for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divId = divs[i];
        div = document.getElementById(divId);
        if(visibleDivId === divId) {
          div.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          div.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

```
<select>
<option onclick="divVisibility('2019ruduo');">2019 Rudens sezonas</option>
<option onclick="divVisibility('2019vasara');">2019 Vasaros sezonas</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the JavaScript onclick event not work on <select> <option>'s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029907/does-the-javascript-onclick-event-not-work-on-select-options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onclick attributes are not supported on option elements. Change it to onchange and move it to your select instead, like this:

```js
function divVisibility(value) {
 alert('Selected: ' + value);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="divVisibility(this.value)">
    <option value="2019ruduo">2019 Rudens sezonas</option>
    <option value="2019vasara">2019 Vasaros sezonas</option>
</select>
```